# What exactly is psychometric modelling?

Tags: modeling, definition, psychometrics

My current definition of **psychometric modelling** is as follows:

> The construction, via statistical tools such as the Rasch or DINA
>   model, of a simplified reprensentation of the operations that lead
>   from the items to the responses.

I am looking to correct and improve my definition.

Based on this question about statistical model but I am looking for an answer that is specific to psychometrics: [What exactly is building a statistical model?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/63074/what-exactly-is-building-a-statistical-model)